# XPathDocument with XPathNavigator VS Xmlreader?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, performance

I saw this question :

[XPathDocument vs. XmlDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135897/xpathdocument-vs-xmldocument)

But it doesnt have the info which im looking for: 
my question :

I know that XPathDocument  Loads the *complete* xml into the memory :

My question is from the stage where the xml is **already** loaded  :

which one of them will **faster find** the desired elements  :

> XPathDocument with XPathNavigator

or

> xmlReader with If's conditions

Comment: Do you expect a big difference?

Comment: @henk I expect  NULL difference , since I dont know the answer , I asked here on stackOverflow :)

Comment: The answer is: speed won't matter. Use the approach that is most convenient to solve your issue.

Comment: @HenkHolterman speed Won't matter ? mmmmmm.....I disagree with you.. sorry :)

Comment: Because you first load the document. You need an awful lot of searching to get to 1% of the time the I/O took.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by

> "the xml is already loaded"

you mean that it's already going to be loaded into an XPathDocument or XmlDocument, then the performance of using either the XPathNavigator or XmlReader will be the same.  Both will be traversing already parsed, in-memory nodes representing the XPath data model.

The main difference between the two is the XmlReader will provide forward-only access whereas the XPathNavigator provides cursor access to the document.  Directly interacting with XmlReader is very useful when you don't want to incur the cost of loading entire document in-memory.  It's not so useful otherwise.

I'd strongly suggest using the XPathNavigator.
There are two primary ways you can interact with the XPathNavigator:

1. Build your state machine (using if/elses).  One huge plus of doing this with the XPathNavigator rather than the XmlReader is, due to the cursor access model of XPathNavigator, your state machine will be vastly simpler. Ex: Need to see if the parent has a specific attribute?  Just navigate to it and take a look.
2. Use XPath queries to find the data you're looking for.  May not be as fast, but will probably will be less error prone than building your own state machine.  Of course this requires you to be versed in XPath.